# C# : Run Excel without File.WriteAllBytes

Tags: c#, excel-interop

How to run Excel without creating a file? (File.WriteAllBytes) do you have any suggestions for protecting the excel from being copied by the user?

```
public void openExcel()
{

            string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath(); 
         
 
            string excelPath = Path.Combine(tempPath , fileName);
          
            File.WriteAllBytes(excelPath, Properties.Resources.excel);
            
            Excel.Application excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
            Excel._Workbook excelWorkbook;
            
            excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(excelPath, Password: "1234");

            excelApplication.Visible = true;

            
}
```

Comment: *How to run Excel without creating a file?* - `Process.Start("excel.exe");` ?

Comment: *protecting the excel from being copied by the user?* - how do you propose stopping someone from copying a file on their computer?

Comment: @CaiusJard Process.Start("excel.exe") is not open my embedded  Resources file

Comment: Suffice to say: even if you were able to pass a whole file to Excel via shared memory or something without saving it, the user could get it from Excel anyway. You are wasting your time.

Comment: So, this looks like an XY problem; you need to do X, you e decided Y is the best way to do it, you e hit a problem implementing Y and you've come here. Tell us what X is; we might be able to suggest Y2

Comment: @Charlieface Can be prevented via vba

Comment: @CaiusJard I want a software like "LockXls"

Comment: No it cannot because there are always workarounds